# Python / Why can't I install last version of Pyarrow?

Tags: python-3.x, pyarrow

When I try to install in my virtual env pyarrow, by default this command line installs the version 6.0.1

```
python -m pip install pyarrow
```

When I try to upgrade this command produces an error

```
python -m pip install pyarrow==7.0.0
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> pyarrow==7.0.0 (from versions: 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.7.1,
> 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 2.0.0, 3.0.0, 4.0.0, 4.0.1, 5.0.0, 6.0.0, 6.0.1) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyarrow==7.0.0

In the [official page](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/#history), last version is 9.0.0

My python version is 3.6.6

What could be the cause ?

Comment: Are you using Python3.6? Version 6.0.1 was the last to support 3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the line in https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/e90472e35b40f58b17d408438bb8de1641bfe6ef/python/setup.py#L621, `pyarrow>=7` requires Python>=3.7. Thus you won't be able to use it with Python 3.6.x. Thus if you want to use a newer `pyarrow` version, you also need to update your Python version.